# How do I know whether an Asterisk call is inbound or outbound (in the Asterisk code)?

Tags: asterisk

I am working on Asterisk code and trying to determine, within a section of source code, whether a call is in-bound or out-bound.  The module I am looking at is res_format_attr_h264.c  I want the SDP behavior to be different between in-bound and out-bound calls when dealing with H264

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is check SIPHeader, which is unset for outbound.

Sure can be other ways. Likly you can check context variables(see tcpdump)

Comment: Which header? I am in the file res_format_attr_h264.

Comment: A well known asterisk engineer actually said this is not possible, as I thought.  Thanks for your ideas though!

Comment: Depend of cost as always.